# How to point all folders and files to root?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I want to point all subfolders and non-existent files to root folder.

www.domain.com/folder/david to www.domain.com/folder/

or

www.domain.com/folder/david/ to www.domain.com/folder/

Comment: htaccess rewrite rules but they don't work

Comment: And those rules are? Please put the rules you have tried in your question.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*) ?$       http://www.domain.com/folder$1 [L,R]

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file stored in `/folder/`?

Comment: no in the parent folder

Comment: And is `/david/` an actual folder?

Comment: I want  it to work for both wether it is a folder, file or it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Make sure the requested path does not exist (file or folder):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If it doesn't exist, redirect it to `/folder/`
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/?$ /folder/? [NC,R,L]
```

The `NC` flag makes the rule case-insensitive. If you do not need it, you can remove it.

If you would like to make the redirect permanent, exchange the `R` flag for `R=301`.

If it doesn't matter whether or not it exists, use the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect everything to `/folder/`
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/?$ /folder/? [NC,R,L]
```

#### Update

Based on your comments, it appears you are running an application in `/folder/`. As such, it would be better to place your `.htaccess` file in `/folder/`, and fill it with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /folder/

# Make sure the requested path does not exist (file or folder):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If it doesn't exist, rewrite it to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

You then do not need an `.htaccess` file inside the root - only the one in `/folder/` is needed.

Comment: It worked , but I want to see the old url but anonimously pointed to parent folder

Comment: www.domain.com/folder/david to www.domain.com/folder/ but the first url not to be changed

Comment: What is in `/folder/`? An `index.php` file, perhaps?

Comment: And will this file handle the request?

Comment: how to rewrite all urls ending by slash to removed slash?